# How to change the message of Verify.js?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the text that prompt when the data-validate returns false when submitting the form using [Verify.js](http://verifyjs.com/)

form:

```
<form>
  <input name="test" value="" data-validate="required">
  <input type="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

I tried to use this in an external js file but it doesn't work :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $.verify.updateRules({required:{message:"another text"}});
    });
```

Comment: Can you also include the form input?

Comment: Also, can you expand on "text to be in another language"

Comment: Post editted.
I want to change the text of the message.
See the plugin link for examples

Comment: So I logged `Object.keys($.verify)` and didn't see `updateRules`. It seems like it's being referenced here: https://github.com/jpillora/verifyjs/blob/2e9ef71e4866deee367e3d0b1832f29d7fe1a34e/src/modules/5.init.js#L50, but it doesn't actually have a `ruleManager.updateRules` to map to.

Seems like you may be working with a younger validation project and may want to explore other options!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting this here as the "answer"... after looking into this, I've decided to enter it in as an issue on the Verify.js repo: https://github.com/jpillora/verifyjs/issues/32

While Verify.js improves the stability of their API, I advise you to use http://jqueryvalidation.org/. It's very mature and easy to use. For you use case, you may be interested in the `rules` fn:

```
$( ".test" ).rules( "add", {
  required: true,
  minlength: 2,
  messages: {
    required: "Required input",
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("must be at least {0} characters")
  }
});
```

Comment: See where the value string of "Required input" is? You can make that whatever you want. So, in my example, "test" is a class of an input that yells "Required input" whenever there's no value and "must be at least ..." whenever there's not enough characters. You can change these to whatever you want. This library is very powerful and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the verify js file and make a search for

```
//public interface 
ruleManager = {
  addFieldRules: addFieldRules,
  ...
```

and you extend the list with this line:

```
updateRules: updateRules,
```

it will work. It worked for me.